# Wordpress Help - 502 on other pages but not on main age

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

My main page is showing up on wordpress but when I go to other pages such as mainpage.com/contact-us, that has a php code in it, gives me a 502 bad gateway. I've done some configs on both php5-fpm and nginx but it doesn't seem to be working at all. Any help is greatly appreciated.

NGINX.conf

```
nginx.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 8192;
  multi_accept on;
  use epoll;
}


http {
  ##
  # Reverse
  ##
  set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
  real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
  add_header X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1";


  fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
  fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300;




  ##
  # Rockin Defaults
  ##
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  server_name_in_redirect off;
  client_max_body_size 512k;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  index index.php index.html
 ##
  # Logging Settings
  ##
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  ##
  # Gzip Settings
  ##
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_static on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_types text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  ##
  # Virtual Host Configs
  ##
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
upstream php {

    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

}
```

nginx/sites-enabled/wordpress

```
fastcgi_cache_path /mnt/ramdisk/phpfpm-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:5M max_size=1G inactive=2h;

server {
  listen 8080 default;
  server_name localhost;
  access_log /mnt/access.log;
  error_log /mnt/error.log;
  root   /var/www/;
  index index.php index.html;
  client_max_body_size    10m;
  client_body_buffer_size 128k;
  client_header_buffer_size 64k;

  location = /favicon.ico {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|zip|gz|tar)$ {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @memcache;
  }

  location ~ /\. {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    deny all;
}

 location ~* /(fpm.www.status|fpm.www.ping)$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri @memcache;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $args;
  }

  # Keeping this in by default. It will _always_ fail for 127.0.0.1 since
  # there is no local memcache server. This might change for the default
  # setup in the future, but for now it's essentially a redirect to @rewrite
  location @memcache {
    default_type text/html;

    set $memcached_key data-$scheme://$host$request_uri;
    memcached_pass 127.0.0.1:11211;
    error_page 404 = @rewrite;
  }

  location @rewrite {
    index index.php;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_hide_header 'X-Generator';
    fastcgi_read_timeout 14400;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME     /index.php;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $args;
  }


}
```

WWW.CONF for PHP5-fpm

```
; -------------------------------------------------------------------- ;
; first pool
; -------------------------------------------------------------------- ;

[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
#listen.allowed_clients = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock


request_slowlog_timeout = 10s
slowlog = /mnt/logs/php-fpm/$pool.slowlog.log

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 100
pm.start_servers = 4
pm.min_spare_servers = 4
pm.max_spare_servers = 15
pm.max_requests = 5000
listen.backlog = -1
listen.mode = 0666

; http://url/status
; http://url/status?json
; http://url/status?html
pm.status_path = /fpm.$pool.status
ping.path = /fpm.$pool.ping
ping.response = "pong. $pool OK"

request_terminate_timeout = 120s
rlimit_files = 131072
rlimit_core = unlimited
catch_workers_output = no

php_admin_value[error_log] = /mnt/php5/php-error.log

; this is untested will do this on a later update
env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
env[PATH] = $PATH
env[TMP] = /mnt/tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /mnt/tmp
env[TEMP] = /mnt/tmp
```

Lastly the error Log that I'm getting:

```
2014/08/05 18:23:44 [error] 25991#0: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 99.243.124.199, server: localhost, request: "GET /contact-us/ HTTP/1.0", upstream: "memcached://127.0.0.1:11211", host: "107.150.29.134", referrer: "http://107.150.29.134/
```

"

Comment: Look into the nginx errorlog.

Comment: And post your nginx/php5-fpm config.

Comment: editted with everything @CharlotteDunois

Comment: The error seems to be related to not being able to connect to the memcached server defined in `@memcache`. Try bypassing it and go straight to `@rewrite` to see if that works.

Comment: @doublesharp how will I go about doing that?

Comment: In `nginx/sites-enabled/wordpress` change `try_files $uri $uri/ @memcache;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ @refresh;` as well as similar lines and then restart nginx.